# Should we disable closing questions as duplicates which are older than x days?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I recently came upon several questions which were closed years after originally asked (e.g. [Equivalent of .try() for a hash to avoid "undefined method" errors on nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6224875/278842) was closed 4 years after being asked). This strikes me as rather inefficient:

- The original purpose of flagging duplicates has already passed, namely to focus attention of respondents on a single place to create great answers.
- The questions had already been answered to and the answer was accepted. By closing the question as a duplicate, this made the answers seem less credible, even though at least one of them perfectly answered the question.
- In retrospect the closing was often in the wrong direction. The closed question had higher value (as indicated by Google sending me there) rather than the linked one.

I would propose:

- Questions with an accepted answer can not be closed as duplicates more than 30 days after the answer was accepted.

Comment: Duplicates that have accepted answers do not auto-redirect, therefore there is no value lost in dupe closing duplicates that are older and have an accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, so why is it possible to dupe-close them at all?

Comment: A duplicate closure banner is far less temporary, and far more visible, than a comment

Comment: _“By closing the question as a duplicate, this made the answers seem less credible”_ — How so? _“The closed question had higher value (as indicated by Google sending me there)”_ — How Google sorts things doesn’t necessarily reflect the rules and quality standards of Stack Overflow. I don’t see what we would gain from preventing duplicate closure of old questions. The closure is still correct and it’s a good thing to link similar questions together.

Comment: *“By closing the question as a duplicate, this made the answers seem less credible” — How so?* The banner indicates to must users that the linked questions have better answers otherwise why would somebody have linked to them?

Comment: Closure is not primarily for linking questions together. Closure is preventing further answers.

Comment: It is for both, when dealing with dupes.

Comment: *A duplicate closure banner is far less temporary, and far more visible, than a comment* @KevinB - My take is that this visibility is rarely deserved for questions that had accepted answers.

Comment: *@SebastianSimon: I don’t see what we would gain from preventing duplicate closure of old questions.* I find that the duplicate links **in these cases** are often of lower quality than the original post.

Comment: Never trust the question author to know what is right. The acceptance mark should be no indication to you what is good or not. Just because there is an accepted answer doesn't mean that it is good.

Comment: "*Closure is not primarily for linking questions together. Closure is preventing further answers.*" except *duplicate closure* which does both.

Comment: @Karel: The way I read it, all the top answers to this question highlight that it would be beneficial to stop closing old questions.

Answer (score 12):

The age of the question doesn't matter at all when performing curation activities. Whether it was asked 10 years ago or 10 minutes ago doesn't change the fact that there might be a question that has better answers.

The purpose of closing as a duplicate is to direct readers to a place where they can find more accurate or better answers. As long as the question is visible on the internet people will search for it and they expect the best answers possible. Linking a question that has a lot of traffic to the question that has better answers is a huge win. It's our way of telling users of Stack Overflow that despite them landing on a particular question we believe they can find their solution elsewhere.

If you encounter questions that you think have better answers on another question then please close them as duplicates, regardless of their age or of whichever is newer/older.

Comment: Sorry, this misguided as far as I am concerned. Voting, editing and tags in that order are the means by which quality is surfaced. Curation is just meddling in most cases. After many years in particular.

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek I am sorry to disappoint you, but if it wasn't for all of our curation efforts Stack Overflow wouldn't be what it is now. If you are looking at the age of the question and you refrain from taking certain actions because of it then you are doing a disservice to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

I can see the argument about a newer dupe target not being as effective or as valuable as the older dupe target.  Maybe that's a conversation to have instead: reverse the direction of the dupe targets instead.

Disable closing duplicates based on this criteria?  I'd...rather not.  The cases in which an older question being closed as a dupe of a newer question being less effective are still relatively rare, and I feel like coming across this is a papercut that - thankfully - Meta Stack Overflow has the right size of bandage to fix.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. I am maybe just confused why we want this kind of retroactive management of posts. The question wasn't a duplicate for 4 years. Why should it be now? It feels random and is often low quality.

Comment: This is something we've been doing to keep common questions together and to avoid us from having to repeat discussions on how to solve something very specific.  Age doesn't really matter in the same context since technology may get out of date, or the best way to do things may shift over time, and new solutions could come up that could generally answer the problem.  No reason to deny that kind of expression, even if it is clumsy as hell.

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek "*The question wasn't a duplicate for 4 years.*" - it very well might have been. Just nobody managed to dupe close it. Especially back when we needed 5 close votes, closures would sometimes fail to get traction. Or perhaps nobody happened upon both questions. So, "wasn't a duplicate" is not necessarily the case. There is the situation where a *newer* question is posted and it's of higher quality, so the older gets dupe closed against it. That also happens - that's how we get self-answered canonicals - none of the existing questions are good enough, so a user creates one.